# Excel Data Verification using COUNTIF

Tags: excel

Ok, I'm going to try to explain this the best I can. :) I have a excel spreadsheet with two tabs. Tab1 has information that is imported from user feedback on a web site while Tab2 has data in it copied from a database.

There's two columns in Tab1 that I'd like to verify the data that is in the cell's of these columns with the data that is in Tab2 and then display True or False in its own column depending on whether the data from Tab1 matches the data in Tab2.

I've figured out how to use COUNTIF to verify cells from one column but I can't figure out how to get it to verify both columns in Tab1 from Tab2. Here is what I have so far: `=COUNTIFS(Rosters!A:B,B10:C10)>0`

In the example above, if I delete either B10 or C10, then it works but only verifying the cells in the one column. If I leave it as B10:C10 it shows as false even though it should be true based on the data in Tab2. Is there a way to verify data in multiple columns in a Tab from data that is in another Tab or spreadsheet??

This is what I tried for multiple criteria, but it's still showing as false even though it should be true: `=COUNTIFS(Rosters!A:B,B10, Rosters!A:B,C10)>0`

Comment: Break it out into multiple criteria. That's the point of `countifs` vs `countif`?

Comment: Try `=COUNTIFS(Rosters!A:A,B10, Rosters!B:B,C10)>0`

Comment: @ScottCraner That did it! I feel so silly. Instead of using `Rosters!A:B` it should have been `A:A` for one column and then `B:B` for the second column. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A8;sheet2!A:A;1;));"FALSE";"TRUE")
```